# How can I disable shift (or any modifier) for some keys but not for others?

Tags: karabiner

I have a bad habit of using right shift to write quotes (""). See, I just did it right there.

I'd like to disable the specific combination of `R_SHIFT+"` so I'm forced to use the left shift.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I think I'll eventually expand this to all of the keys on the right side of the keyboard too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to edit your `~/.config/karabiner/karabiner.json` file and simply define a:

```
"from": { "key_code": "quote",
          "modifiers":{ "mandatory": ["right_shift"] } },
  "to":[ {"key_code": "vk_none"} ],
"type":   "basic"
```

manipulator.
See how to use K-E's event definitions at [Karabiner-Elements' Reference Manual](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html) page.

Comment: Great! Now is this extensible easily (without having to copy and paste it? Like can I do this:
`"from": { "key_code": "quote", "colon", "period", "questionmark"...`

Comment: Not the way you propose it here. If you want to exclude some other "right_shift" combinations you'll indeed have to copy, paste and adapt above code - making a manipulator for each one. . . . . . If you want _NO combination with "right_shift"_ to work you'd rather do: `"from": {"key_code": "right_shift"}, "to":[{"key_code": "vk_none"}], "type":   "basic"` . . . . .  If, on the other hand, you'd want to "keep" just very few combinations, you'd just define those in front of this "general" solution in your karabiner.json file.

Comment: Gotcha, yea I'm blocking a lot of keys on the right side of the keyboard that way, so it would have been nice. But this way works like a charm, thanks so much!

Comment: I haven't gotten this to work.  I have some `right_command` combinations, then below them I disable right_command.  But Karabiner is disabling Command always:
`{
  "from": {
      "key_code": "u",
      "modifiers": {
          "mandatory": [
              "right_command"
          ]
      }
  },
  "to": [
      {
          "key_code": "up_arrow"
      }
  ],
  "type": "basic"
},
{
  "from": {
      "key_code": "right_command"
  },
  "to": [
      {
          "key_code": "vk_none"
      }
  ],
  "type": "basic"
}
`

Comment: Hi, I didn't see a fault in your exemplary code above. Maybe there is one bracket too much or one got lost in your "positive" right_command-codes in the json-file?    (In my experience that's most often a reason for failing). Sorry I didn't help directly...